# Regular expression to match a string literal followed by a number

Tags: regex, url

I am using Google Analytics to see which pages are viewed the most of a website, and I need a selection based on a Regular Expression.

What I need to select:

```
/index.php?page=1203
/index.php?page=12
/index.php?page=15&print=1
```

Basically I first need to select the literal string of `/index.php?page=` appended by any number of any length, all integers, so no comma's. After this, anything can be appended so I am thinking an `*` will do. But please answer one with, and without the `*` because I need to target both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex with a captured group:

```
\/index\.php\?page=(\d+)
```

We are capturing 1+ digits in 1st capture group after matching text `/index.php?page=`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but Google Analytics throws an error saying it's an invalid Regex, the rules for Regex within GA are listed here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en. Not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: I edited my question, because I need to look for the literal string of /index.php?page= and not index.php?page= not sure if this cause the error.

Comment: The regex above is using a lookbehind : the construct `(?<=EXPRESSION)` . This is not supported in all regular expression engines (including javascript)

Comment: Alright removed lookbehind from my regex. Try it now, you number will be available in backreference # 1

Comment: Thanks for the edit @anubhava, and the noite by James. It works!

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Sorry I didn't know much about `Google Analytics regex` capabilities that's why I gave lookbehind based regex earlier.

Comment: Ta. Note the regex above will not include the &print=1 in your last example. If you need this bit as well then try `\/index\.php\?page=(\d+)(&[^\s]+)?` (ie the previous expression optionally followed by an & and one or more non-whitespace characters.